# Sorting array of dictionaries by value after for loop?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary

I've seen a lot of answers to similar questions but none of the methods have worked so far.

```
if let users = snapshot.value!["users"] as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject> {

 each.users = Int(users.count)

var pointsArray = [Dictionary<String,Int>]()
   for (key, value) in users {


              let uid = key
              let points = value["points"] as! Int
              pointsArray.append([uid : points])

                        }
```

I'm then needing to sort pointsArray by the "points", sort it from high to low, grab the 0th (highest) element, then grab the uid to use.

I've tried:

```
  var myArr = Array(pointsArray.keys)
    var sortedKeys = sort(myArr) {
    var obj1 = dict[$0] // get ob associated w/ key 1
    var obj2 = dict[$1] // get ob associated w/ key 2
    return obj1 > obj2
           }
```

This gives me

```
Value of type [ Dictionary <String,Int>] has no member keys.
```

I guess that's cause I'm trying to run the sort on my array of dicts vs the dicts themselves? How do I switch this up to get into the actual dictionaries vs. running the sort on the array?

Comment: I am, but for some reason I couldn't figure out how to pull the values in the way I wanted from firebase so I just made my own dictionary. I'd definitely prefer to use orderedByValue here if possible.  

I'll post my observation / database structure in an edit? Although at this point with how things are set up it might be easier to just sort this dictionary.

Comment: Here is an answer to your deleted comment, if you haven't found one:

You need to access the key of bestScore like this: bestScore.keys.first.
Same mistake here - bestScore is a dictionary and it has keys, not key. Moreover, it is a dictionary containing only one elements, that's why bestScore.keys.first works. Read more about dictionaries here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH8-ID105

Comment: @leo 
Thankkk you. I thought Ii had figured it out then deleted and then it turned out I hadn't and I didn't want to spam your notifications lol. 

Thanks a lot for the help man I apprecaite it a ton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right - you're not properly accessing the keys of the dictionaries.

Here's a working code:

```
var pointsArray = [Dictionary<String, Int>]()

pointsArray.append(["1" : 10])
pointsArray.append(["2" : 45])
pointsArray.append(["3" : 30])

// sort by points
let sorted = pointsArray.sort({ $0.first!.1 > $1.first!.1 })

print(sorted) // [["2": 45], ["3": 30], ["1": 10]]
```

---

`Array(pointsArray.keys)` - this doesn't work, because `pointsArray` is an `array`, therefore it doesn't have `keys` property. The contents of `pointsArray` are dictionaries and they have `keys`. So you can access the keys of the first dictionary like this: `pointsArray[0].keys`